# What Capital Gains are owed for a Non-resident owning stock in US C corporation when it is acquired?

Tags: united-states, stocks, non-resident, capital-gains-tax, employee-stock-options

Would a non-resident alien (no connection to the US apart from the company) owning founder/CEO stock (not stock options) of a private US corporation have to pay capital gains tax in the event that the company was acquired?

Background: I incorporated a US company and have issued myself (and others) stock (employee stock plan that is actual stock, not options) in the company for $0.001c (or a similar low price) when we started. The company's revenue is 100% from US based customers.

Comment: You should probably talk to an accountant who's familiar with the US tax law, your home country tax law, and the tax treaty between the US and your home country.

Comment: You also didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: There is a question buried in the last sentence

Comment: Maybe first sentence, post edit?